# How separate PDO Query result and echo in separate table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello,

```
            while($r = $q->fetch())
             { 
               for($i=0 ; $i<$colcount; $i++)
                echo "<td> $r[$i] \t</td>";
             }
```

Its Work fine.

But i need to Display Only 10 records in 1st table and next 10 records in next table .
IT Display all records in one Table.
Here i already counted total record in **$totalrecords** .So how to use it.

How Display only  10 Record on 1st table and and next 10 on onather table

Comment: can you post more code including tables as well

Comment: Add LIMIT 10 to your SQL. This will limit it to only 10 records. You may also want to use ORDER BY, to order the results correctly so the 10 required are returned. If you say get record id 100 from the first table and want 101-110 from the second then you need to use that id and do something like id > 100 on the second statement.

Comment: !Learner -which code you want .  it disaply perfect .                  !The Humble Rat -here i cant chage SQl . i only get query reslut. And my page display that Query Result in specific table or forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$rows = $q->fetchAll();
$i = 0;

echo '<table>';

// display 10 first records
while ($i < 10 && $i < $totalrecords) {
   echo $rows[$i++];
}

echo '</table><table>';

// display 10 next records
while ($i < 12 && $i < $totalrecords) {
   echo $rows[$i++];
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Here $rows is an array of all records, so $rows[$i] is strictly equivalent to your $q->fetch()
See the php manual for more information http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php